# How can I refresh the page when a form is submitted & give an error message?

Tags: php, email, refresh, action

What I have right now is a form with simple input fields such as name, phone number, email, and comment.

```
<div id="specialsForm"><h3>Interested in this coupon? Email us! </h3>           
<form method="post" action="emailMonthlySpecials.php">    
Name: <input name="name" type="text" /><br />
Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
Phone Number: <input name="phone" type="text" /><br /><br />
Comment: <br/>
<textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Email"/>
</form></div>
```

In my emailMonthlySpecials.php I have the following code:

```
 $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'] ;

  if(!empty($name) && (!empty($email) || !empty($phone))) {
  mail("my.email@hotmail.com", "Monthly Specials Email",
    "Name: $name 
     Email: $email 
     Phone Number: $phone
     Comment: $comment", "From: $email" );

  } else {
    echo '<span class="error">A name, comment, phone number/email is required</span><br />'; 
  };
```

It goes to a new page and shows the error (if there is one) and if not it goes to a blank page (I know how to make it go to a thank you page but it needs to be kept on its current page) It does work with sending the info to the email.

I have tried

```
  header("Location: ".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
```

And it didnt work.. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not refresh on errors

Comment: How do I stop it from going to the blank page then? Cause if I dont direct it somewhere it just goes to a blank page, but still emails properly

Comment: Do not display blank page but rather the same page with filled form. Make it all on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the page that displays the form also be where the form is submitted to.  That was if there is an error the page can just continue and show the form again.  ie.

contact.php (pseudo code)

```
<?

if ([form submitted]) {

    if ([fields filled out correctly]) {
        [send mail]
        header('location: thankyou.php');
    } else {
        $error = 'error message';
    }

}

?>

<span class="error"><?=$error;?></span>
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    [field]
</form>
```

You can also use redirects, but you will need to store the message in [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) variables to carry it over to the other page.

Comment: `Have the page that displays the form also be where the form is submitted to` - to do so, just leave form's action blank

Comment: Thank you! What would I write to make sure it was sent? In this area: if ([form submitted])

Comment: Give the submit button a 'name' attribute (ie. <input type="submit" name="send_email" value="Submit Email" /> and then check: if(array_key_exists('send_email', $_POST)) { }

Answer (score -2):

If you want to redirect back to the caller, then you have to write this:

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Comment: They still need the error message back on the original page though.